# Value Axis move issue in kendo stock chart

Tags: jquery

I have been working with Kendo ui stock chart, And am facing Issue that the value axis moves while changing date selection.Can Anyone help me to fix this issue .?

Thanks In advance

Comment: can you make a fiddle so someone can sort it out

Comment: Can I share the snapshot for this issue ?